# Error: Unable to access jarfile when running docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jar

I am getting the following error when trying to run a docker container:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile
```

My Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install Updates
RUN apt-get update -y && \
     apt-get upgrade -y && \
     apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
     apt-add-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa && \
     apt-get update -y && \
     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/cache/*

# Install Packages
RUN apt-get -qq update -y && \
    apt-get -q install -y \
        wget \
        openssh-server \
        openjdk-8-jdk \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/cache/*

# Add the config files
ADD /apps/ /home/smartling/

# Adding the jar application
ADD /apps/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/repo-connector-1.5.4.jar /home/smartling/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/

# Making sure the files are there
RUN ls -la /home/smartling/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/

# Start the jar file when container launches
CMD ["java","-jar","/home/smartling/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/repo-connector-1.5.4.jar -start&"]
```

Then I build

```
docker build -t smartlingflagship .
```

Everything comes back successful

The I run the container

```
docker run --rm --name smartlingconn smartlingflagship
```

And it comes back with the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/smartling/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/repo-connector-1.5.4.jar -start&
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding this to the bottom          `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","repo-connector-1.5.4.jar"]
CMD ["-start"]`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the response of:

```
RUN ls -la /home/smartling/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/
```

Check if the file `repo-connector-1.5.4.jar` is having the required permission to run. If not please use `chmod` and grant the jar the permission.

Command is as follow:

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/smartling/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/repo-connector-1.5.4.jar"]
```

Place the above command after `#` Making sure the files are there

```
RUN ls -la /home/smartling/flagship/repo-connector-1.5.4/
```

Comment: It didn't work. Still same error. In the output of the build the file permissions were (-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 217456 Oct 19  2016 repo-connector-1.5.4.jar)

Comment: Hello teej2542, I see you are running the jar with -start&. Docker requires atleast 1 process running in the foreground to start up. Could you please run the jar in the foreground instead of background.